# Import the Wikipedia database: create table structure

Tags: mysql, import, mediawiki

I downloaded a Wikipedia dump XML file, converted it to .sql using AmoK's xml2sql script.

When I try to import it using mysqldump, I got references to not existing database or tables. For example, **`data.siteinfo`** doesn't exist.

I don't want to create each table manually. I was wondering if someone has a query for creating all table structures.

This is what I downloaded and convert it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia_database#Where_do_I_get...

Do you have any tips for me?

Comment: I've found this article

http://svn.wikimedia.org/viewvc/mediawiki/trunk/phase3/maintenance/tables.sql?view=markup

I can't post the sql code because is way too long but you can find it there!

Comment: If this solves your problem, you're encouraged to post yourself an answer, so other people can benefit of your solution. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the [import instructions](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Data_dumps/Tools_for_importing).

Tables in your database are created by the MediaWiki installation. Then they are *populated* by the import. Depending on the import procedure you chose, some tables may finally need to be rebuilt based on the data from their "source" tables.